# Modifying the content of Texture array on the fly

Tags: cuda, textures

I want to modify the cuda array's content periodically, to which i have a texture reference in the device code. Note that update on array is to be done in the host code. My question is: can we do this concurrently, that is the device kernel is to be invoked only once and array content changes periodically and are reflected in the device memory.

Comment: CUDA arrays exist in device memory, and the host cannot directly write to device memory or CUDA arrays.  The only ways you can write to CUDA arrays are via memcpy or in a CUDA kernel with surface references.  There's no guarantee that you can do either of those operations when a kernel is already running; both the original kernel invocation and the memcpy (or other kernel) would have to be in non-NULL streams, but the programming model makes no guarantee that operations in different streams will actually run concurrently.  Anyway, coherency is enforced between kernel invocations.

Comment: But i can make changes through  texture refrence, which should get reflected i suppose.
This means i have to invoke the kernel as many time as required..

Comment: Texture references are read-only.  If you write to a CUDA array using a *surface reference*, that memory traffic goes through the L1/L2 cache hierarchy and is not coherent with the texture cache.

Answer (score 5):

If you modify the cudaArray from the host, changes are not guaranteed to be reflected in the texture memory. Because the texture is cached. At the time where you modify the cudaArray on the host, you don't know which part of that memory is cached by texture and which is not.

The only guarantee that changes are completely reflected in the device code, is when kernel has finished its execution.

Comment: So if I modify the contents of a CUDA array between kernel invocations I’m ok? i.e. I don’t have to recreate the texture object with a new array?

Comment: @wcochran... Yes, modification of `cudaArray` between kernel calls should be fine.